# Typescript Ordered Dictionary

Tags: typescript, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I need to store relatively big amount of data sorted with index, something similar to editable chat - ordered by time and with random access for editing.

The number of items are relatively big and the number of "index" operation is similar to the number of "sort" actions. I don't prevent the calculation of the "search" or the "sort" each time and I search for smarter collection.

I tried to find Ordered Dictionary collection, but I just saw solutions that use regular dictinary and calculate `Object.values(dict).sort()` which is too expansive, I believe, if `dict` is big and you need to sort if every ~1sec.

TL;DR
Is there Ordered Dictionary collection or something similar in TypeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). A Map is guaranteed to keep the order of insertion while you're iterating it.

Objects might work for you too. Since ES2015, the iteration order is not exactly insert-order, but [it is predictable](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/).

I prefer to use Maps over Objects when the keys come from user input or when they aren't properties of a known shape. It's similar to Dictionaries vs. Records in other languages you might be familiar with.

Comment: Is there a way to insert item in the middle?