# Typescript (Lodash) Dictionary order

Tags: typescript, sorting, dictionary, lodash

I have a lodash Dictionary which looks like this:
{
5: "e",
2: "b",
3: "c",
1: "a",
4: "d"
}
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60802305/typescript-ordered-dictionary) and in the link attached in the answer, that typescript iteration order is guaranteed for objects. Is it also guaranteed for lodash Dictionaries? I couldn't solid information on the subject.
I want to create a dropdown sorted by key in descending order, and I thought if the iteration order is guaranteed I can just use

```
_(myDict).reverse().value()
```

Is the order guaranteed? Will it work?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the word "dictionary" in [the lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15). Do you mean "object"?

Comment: Lodash doesn't have dictionaries. What you show is a regular object. Lodash just manipulates normal data - objects, arrays, plain values, etc. Any internal data structures are pretty much never leaked to the outside. `_(myDict).reverse().value()` will most definitely unwrap the Lodash chainable and give you back the value. If `myDict` is an object (as it seems here), you'd get an object back.

Comment: *"and in the link attached in the answer, that typescript iteration order is guaranteed for objects"* JavaScript guarantees it, not TypeScript. Yes, there is a guaranteed order. No, using it is not a good idea. :-) The rules for it are complex. If you need order, use an array or a `Map` (the latter is maintained in order of insertion).

Comment: Related: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219)